# In C++ You Can Have a Pointer to a Function, Can you also have a pointer to a class?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm not talking about a pointer to an instance, I want a pointer to a class itself.

Comment: If it were even possible, which it's not, what good would a pointer to a class even be?

Comment: @Jim Buck: passing it around, using it to instantiate new instances of the class, finding out its members, and all the other fun stuff you do in Java with a java.lang.Class.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, you would need reflection which is also not present in C++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++, classes are not "[first class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object)". The closest you can get is a pointer to its `type_info` instance.

Answer (score 5):

No. A pointer is the address of something in the memory of the computer at run-time.  A class is just a set of instructions to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

As everyone else have already said, it's not possible to have a pointer to a class.

But if the point is to create a new instance from some class chosen at runtime, you might want to check out the Factory Method (or Abstract Factory) design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.  This depends on your context of what you are trying to achieve.  If you simply want a pointer to a **type** then no there is not a way.  A **type** does not live in memory in the sense of a pointer.

There reason I said yes though is some people would consider the virtual table a pointer to a type.  It is possible to get this pointer since the virtual table does exist in memory and can be used to invoke virtual methods with a bit of trickery.

Comment: There is a small problem with that: a class can have multiple virtual tables when using multiple inheritance. Also, if a class inherits from another but does not change any virtual methods, I believe nothing prevents the compiler from merging both classes' virtual tables.

Comment: True but you can still get a pointer to it.  Personally I don't consider this a pointer to a type but plenty of people do so I thought I'd post it for completeness

Answer (score 1):

Unlike true Object-Based languages, a class is not an object in C++, more is the pity. The closest you can come to "pointer to class" is RTTI:

const std::type_info &info = typeid(object expression);

type_info has name() member finction, and they can be compared to each other.

Comment: What languages are those where I can have an object where the type of that object is an object (not an object representing the type nor a factory for said type but where it actually is the type)?

Comment: The one I know for sure is Smalltalk. Java tries to do it with getClass(), but it's inconsistent.

Comment: @arkadly reflection (getClass) is very different from what you describe. With reflection you have an bject representing meta data about a type. (A type is a runtime thing a class is a compile time thing, at least in C++/Java/C# et al). Smalltalk you could be right there though as I remember it's more a compile for said class than the class the object represents. Smalltalk is object based not class based (as oppossed to C++ that's class based)

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but I had to give an answer that is somewhat practical, and Java comes closest of all the widely used languages. May be Python is another candidate, also coming up short. And class in Smalltalk is indeed far less important than in Java or C++ - very true.

Answer (score 1):

A "Class" does not exist.  The only thing you can point to is the data.

The rest of a "Class" is actually a dispatch table.  For each method in the class, the dispatch table has a pointer.  That way, the class points to the correct method of your class regardless of what type it's currently cast to.  This would be useless to access.

Methods in your class (the things pointed to by the dispatch table) are actually just "Functions" that are passed in your class data pointer.   The definition of a method is pretty much that it's a function that takes the classes data as a parameter.  In most C-style languages, that data pointer is hidden but referred to as "this".

The methods for your class may be spread all over the codebase.  Because of parent classes, you're not likely even find these methods adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a (run-time) pointer to a class, but C++ does has a similar compile-time concept: [template parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(programming)).  [Boost](http://www.boost.org) has a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) dedicated to manipulating them and a [traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) library for getting information about classes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how you want to think about pointers, you can have a "pointer" to a class, if by pointer you mean some integral value. Boost allows you to register types and assign a unique integer for every type that you register. If the types you are registering are all classes then you can look up at run-time the code necessary to create an object of the type you want, as long as you have the value of the type you want. But in general, classes aren't first class objects in the language and the best you can hope for is to simulate the behavior you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

True, there is no support for reflection/introspection in built in to C++, but there are a number of libraries that will add many of eg java's Class functionality, and allow a programmer to get an object representing a class, create an instance, etc. google c++ reflection.